# How do I disable Windows notifications from the registry?

Tags: windows, windows-registry, notifications, regedit

Kindly give me the full path of regedit from where I can disable the windows notification. For example if I disable the ctrl+alt+del from regedit, after disabling windows sends me the notification that Task manager have been disable by your administrator. I don't need these type of notification. Kindly guide me.

Answer (score 2):

Just a shot in the dark:

Try to undo the regedit change that you have done to disable the Task Manager, and verify that the notification doesn't arrive any more and that Task Manager is now available.

Then use the Local Group Policy Editor to turn it off:
Go to `User Configuration / Administrative Templates / System / Ctrl+Alt+Delete Options / Remove Task Manager, double-click the Remove Task Manager option, and set the policy to Disabled.

Please note that the notification message is only supposed to happen when you try and launch the Task Manager.